# md-button resize font size to fit button size

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using `md-button` which contains text

the problem is when i'm in low resolution the text is cut and i can't find the proper solution to fix it

if you can please suggest how to do that.

I attached a screenshot in high and low resolution + the css and html

```
<md-dialog id="new_test_draft_dialog" flex=40 flex-md=50 flex-sm=60 flex-xs=80>
    <div>
        <div layout-padding>
            <h2>Save Changes?</h2>
            <div style="padding:5px;" layout-padding>
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
                    <md-button ng-click="draftDialogService.cancel()" class="button_type_1 active">Continue</md-button>
                    <md-button ng-click="draftDialogService.hide()" class="button_type_1 active">Discard</md-button>
                    <md-button ng-click="draftDialogService.hide(saveDraft())" class="button_type_1 active">Save draft</md-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-dialog>
```

The css:

```
/* Buttons */
.button_type.md-button,
.button_type,
.button_type_1 {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution to your problem - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/wWjZBq?editors=1010#0)

The idea is to change the layout of the buttons according to screen size (responsive). I think it is more in line with the Angular Material way of doing things.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout-gt-xs="row" layout-xs="column" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Continue Adding</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Discard Changes</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Save Draft And Exit</md-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Angular Material layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction)

Comment: thanks i checked out your solution but it didn't change anything, the text on the buttons is still cut...

Comment: @LiadLivnat Really? When you say "low resolution" in your question do you mean small screen size? With my example the buttons look okay with a small screen size.

Comment: I mean that the page is responsive, so yes low resolution is 1175, i updated the code, maybe it doesn't affect since it's inside a modal ?

Comment: look at the first dialog attributes maybe need to change something there? <md-dialog id="new_test_draft_dialog" flex=40 flex-md=50 flex-sm=60 flex-xs=80

Comment: @LiadLivnat I've put those buttons in a `md-dialog` and the buttons look okay with a small screen size - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QEAmKm?editors=1010#0